# Windows 8 Professional didn't come with Internet Explorer 10(Metro)

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

When I installed Windows 8 Professional Edition I noticed that Internet Explorer 10 was missing. I tried to find some source to acquire the installer but none of the sites are providing it. One of my colleagues upgraded recently and he got the new Internet Explorer after his installation was completed. So is there a way to acquire the installer?

**Update:** 
I should have mentioned that I was talking about the Metro version.

Comment: So you had what - IE9? Or no IE/browser at all? Did you upgrade/clean install? AFAIK unlike the N editions for both Windows 7 and 8, there are no E editions of Windows 8 available. So this is really strange... Can you check if it's enabled under [Windows Features](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-add-or-remove-unwanted-windows-features-programs-or-apps)? It may have got unchecked by mistake.

Comment: Where do I find "Windows Features"?

Comment: I linked to a tutorial in my comment, in case you missed it.

Comment: If you go to the desktop, is the IE10 icon on the taskbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the "Metro" version it may not be there because you have another browser set as the default browser.  If Internet Explorer is not your default browser then the IE10 Metro app is not available.  It should still be available on the desktop, though.

You can search for "Default prgrams" and make IE the default browser and the Metro IE app should magically appear.

Answer (score 6):

Check to see if it is disabled, Open Control Panel (icon view)

Click "Programs and Features", when it opens click "turn windows features on or off" on the left side

.

[image]

A small window will open and populate a list, be sure Internet Explorer 10 is ticked, if not ticked, tick it and hit ok.

[image]

.

If this does not make IE10 available, go to the desktop and do a <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

Note: While you are at the desktop is there an IE icon on the taskbar?

this will open a file browser, now navigate to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer

does the folder exist? is there a "iexplore".exe in there?

if there is you can drag a shortcut to the desktop and use that temporarily, IE on the start screen may take some more doing to get it functional.

.

[image]

Comment: I followed this procedure however IE still doesnt appear when I search for it or look through the Start Screen.

Comment: you need to answer Karan's comment, add that info to your question using the edit feature.

Comment: @JoelDean Check my edit to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your assistance this helped me in arriving at my solution.

Comment: Glad you solved it.